# Django Pass Country name in URLS

Tags: django, django-urls

I am using Django 1.7.
I am developing an application which is marketplace. So Admin user can add/edit Regionol or Country through admin page.

I need to access the application like `http://localhost/#regional#/admin` and here the regional is Dynamic. all the URLS will have the  in first level except some static pages like Contact, About. How can I write re and match this case and also how can we map it in views?

So of urls configs are

`http://localhost/#regional#/admin
http://localhost/admin
http://localhost/about
http://localhost/#regional#/product`

My client doesn't want multihost though or else it would be easy like `http://<regional>.localhost/`

Pl advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use named groups in your urls:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<region>)/admin$', views.some_view),
)
```

in your some_view() function you do this:

```
def some_view(request, region=""):
```

check for the value of region from the url and proceed accordingly

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this named URL. But I am expecting something else.
Ideally we need to list out the content based on the REGION we have in DB. If there is no REGION, then we need to show the ENTIRE data. 
Also we may have 2 admin urls. One for Regional based http://localhost/#regional#/admin and and another one for SuperAdmin. http://localhost/admin